# Boto3 InvalidParameterException

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I have some code that calls into AWS's Rekognition service. Sometimes it throws this exception:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DetectLabels operation: Request has Invalid Parameters
```

I can't find the `InvalidParameterException` anywhere in the documentation or code, though, so I can't write a specific handler for when that occurs. Does anyone know what library module that exception lives in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it in [`boto/cognito/identity/exceptions.py`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/boto/cognito/identity/exceptions.py):

```
from boto.exception import BotoServerError

class InvalidParameterException(BotoServerError):
    pass
```

Comment: Interesting... do you know if I import `boto` if it'll work in a Python3 application?

Comment: I would say yes as they can live side-by-side, but please try it for me!

Answer (score 8):

If you saw this exception in response to calling `search_faces_by_image` then it probably indicates that there were no detectable faces in the image that you provided. You can review a list of possible exceptions at [API_SearchFacesByImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html).

To handle this exception, you could write code like this:

```
import boto3
rek = boto3.client('rekognition')

def lookup_faces(image, collection_id):
    try:
        faces = rek.search_faces_by_image(
            CollectionId=collection_id,
            Image=image,
            FaceMatchThreshold=95
        )
        logger.info('faces detected: {}'.format(faces))
        return faces
    except rek.exceptions.InvalidParameterException as e:
        logger.debug('no faces detected')
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a misleading error by AWS, this error comes when the source image did not contain any detectable faces. Make sure your source image has a detectable face.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 with boto3 you can do:

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

catch ClientError as e:
```

Comment: ‘ClientError’ is useful, but broader than the exception I was trying to address.

Answer (score 0):

jarmod's answer should work perfect, if you use boto3.

To more explicitly answer the question regarding where the `InvalidParameterException` lives (in `boto3`): It can be acessed via a class instance of the `boto3` rekognition client:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rekognition')
```

Now, the exception can be accessed via `client.exceptions.InvalidParameterException` (see jarmod's answer for a specific example).

Stéphane Bruckert's suggestion of using an import from `boto` did not work for me as the exception does not appear to be caught by a specific handler using this import (but I did not tested it extensively).